# How can I find the row differences of a matrix?

Tags: programming, matrix

How can I compute the row differences of an m x n matrix to obtain an m-1 x n matrix; that is, given

[image]

how do I obtain

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this ?

```
m = {{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}, {g, h, i}};
Differences[m] 
(* {{-a + d, -b + e, -c + f}, {-d + g, -e + h, -f + i}} *)
```

Comment: Thanks @b.gatesucks I didn't know this function existed!

Comment: @sebastian if you are grateful for answers you should be [Accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) some of them too.  You haven't done this for a very long time.  Why not?